# Cannot unmount drive, /var/lib/snapd/snap target is busy

Tags: mount, unmounting

I want to unmount my main drive so I can run fsck on it because dmesg says that I should. However, when I try to unmount the drive I get the following error:

```
Cannot unmount drive, /var/lib/snapd/snap target is busy
```

How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you run

```
lsof /var/lib/snapd/snap/*
```

you will get the pid(s) of running process.

To know what is the full command line:

```
ps uww <PID>
```

Then you can decide if you want to `kill` the process to umount the dir

Answer (score 1):

If by "main drive" you mean your root filesystem, you can't unmount that!

You can remount it read only, that might help.  You should be able to run fsck on a read only filesystem.  However, this is an extreme measure I'd only use if I had no other options.

It might be best (and easiest?) to boot a live disk and run fsck on your root partition from there.  There are several rescue distros that might help with that, including sometimes the install disk for the distro you are using.

Alternately, sometimes the boot process itself already runs fsck and there may be rescue options configured as alternate boot options in your boot loader to do this manually as well.

If by main disk you mean something other than your root filesystem, then you might want to stop the snap service which might automatically unmount some things.  But I suspect you will still need to reboot to do this.